# Why Rebecca says "you're right" to Enid when the blonde guy says "tonight" to others?

Tags: meaning

In Ghost World, there's a scene where a Blonde Guy passes over Rebecca & Enid and says these words to other guys:

> You guys up for some reggae tonight?

And then, Rebecca says these words to Enid:

> OK, you're right.

Why did Rebecca say these words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [more context online](https://sfy.ru/?script=ghost_world), which is necessary for understanding this sentence:

> ```
>   REBECCA     See that guy?
>
>   ENID    Which one?
>
>   REBECCA     He gives me a total boner!
>
>   ENID    He's like the biggest idiot of all time!
> ```
>
> The guy, a COLLEGE SOPHOMORE, walks by them with two friends.
>
> ```
>   COLLEGE SOPHOMORE   Are you guys up for some reggae tonight?
>
>   REBECCA     Okay, you're right.
> ```

Rebecca is responding to Enid's statement that the guy is "the biggest idiot of all time." She's not answering his question about reggae, she is agreeing with Enid that he's an idiot.